# Struts 2 basic web application 404 error

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, struts2

Here is my set up:

Specs:

Tomcat 7.0.40
jdk1.7
Eclipse Juno
Win 8.1
I set up a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse titled "StrutsTest" with following structure. relevent codes are as below:
web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
    version="3.0">
    <display-name>StrutsTest</display-name>
    <filter>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

struts.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
"-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
"http://struts.apache.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">

<struts>
    <include file="struts-default.xml" />
    <package name="a" extends="struts-default">
        <action name="verify" class="com.anirban.strutstest1.LoginAction">
            <result name="success">/success.jsp</result>
            <result name="error">/error.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

index.jsp

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="s" uri="/struts-tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<html>
<body>

    <s:form action="verify">

        <s:textfield name="uname" label="Enter Username" />
        <br>
        <s:password name="password" label="Enter Password" />
        <br>
        <s:submit value="Click" align="center" />

    </s:form>
</body>
</html>
```

LoginAction.java

```
package com.anirban.strutstest1;

import com.opensymphony.xwork2.ActionSupport;


public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private String uname,password;

    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }

    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }

    public String getPassword() {
        return password;
    }

    public void setPassword(String password) {
        this.password = password;
    }

    public String execute()
    {
        if(uname.equals("java4s") && password.equals("pass"))
        {
            return SUCCESS;

        }else
            return ERROR;
    }
}
```

I have tried FilterDispatcher instead of StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter. Even changed my server from Tomcat to JBoss. But still getting same error. Thanks in advance. Below here is the folder structure:

> ```
> Java Resources
>     |_src
>       |_com.anirban.strutstest1
>         |_LoginAction.java
>     |_resources
>       |_struts.xml
>     |_Libraries
> Javascript Resources
> build
> WebContent
>     |_META-INF
>     |_WEB-INF
>       |_lib
>         |_<struts jars>
>       |_web.xml
>     |_<jsp files>
> ```

Comment: There are different kind of 404 errors out there, which one have you got?

Comment: Try removing      `<include file="struts-default.xml" />`

Answer (score 1):

Thanks buddies. I have got the answer.
Jar was older. I have replaced

```
<filter>
    <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter</filter-class>
</filter>
```

with

```
<filter>
       <filter-name>struts2</filter-name>
       <filter-class>org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.FilterDispatcher</filter-class>
</filter>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your action in struts.xml to:

```
<action name="verify" class="com.anirban.strutstest1.LoginAction" method="execute">
```

Also try to put struts.xml in WEB-INF/classes

Comment: `execute` is default method, no point in setting it explicitly.